# android access view with create different class

Tags: java, android, xml

First, my apologies since I'm still a beginner in Android development.
My question: Can I access a view using a different class?  For example, this is my main activity code :

(XML)

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/something_dummy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    />
```

(JAVA)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Controller controller = new Controller();
    controller.setEmptyEditText();



}

}
```

Controller.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Controller extends Activity {

public Controller() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setEmptyEditText(){
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.something_dummy);
    et.setText("");
}
```

}

When I run this app, I get an error and a crash.
I want to know if I can dosomething to the view (in this case, the editText), without writing it in the main activity class.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the other view?

Comment: for this example, i want to empty edittext view from other class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can access a view from outside the mainActivity class. However, it really depends on what you want to do. For example, you can define a custom editText (say, you want an editText that you can empty with one function call).

```
public class myEditText extends EditText{
  public myEditText(Context context){
    super(context);
  }

  public myEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public myEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public setEditTextEmpty(){
    setText("");
  }
```

Now, in your mainActivity, you can access the custom editText:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myEditText et = (myEditText) findViewById(R.id.something_dummy);
    et.setEditTextEmpty();

}

}
```

On a side note, in Android, an Activity is more likely to play the role of the controller, while the editText (and any other views for that matter) are simple dumb views that display stuff. Here are some very nice articles on how to do the controller/view thinggy in Android:

http://www.therealjoshua.com/2011/11/android-architecture-part-1-intro/

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/